# Does spacebar center on Nuke/Worm in StarCraft?

Tags: starcraft-2

I can't test it now, but does spacebar (center on recent event) work for Nydus Worm/Nuke? (eg. if i got nuked or wormed, can I find it by hitting space)

Comment: It did at one time for Nuke. Nydus Worms don't trigger a traditional announcement, so I don't know if it does for them.

Comment: It does not, but makes special sound so you know that a worm is comming. And do you know if it does still or this feature was removed?

Comment: FWIW, you accepted an answer that can be proven wrong. Please see the comments in that answer for details.

Comment: Yep, please mark Shaun's one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never had any success with space bar finding a nuke. I think a lot of people were getting confused by the fact that, **if you did not tell your ghost to "hold fire", he'd fire off some sniper rounds before the nuke. If that happens, your opponent *can* zero in on the "units under attack" event with the space bar**. From there, it gets pretty obvious what's happening.

Nydus worm is the same situation. You can zero in on the attacks happening after the units start pouring out of the worm, but not on the worm coming out of the ground itself.

Comment: For what it's worth, spacebar did work during beta, at least.

Comment: I don't believe that ghost come to place and have a "free time to shot a couple of zerlings" before aiming a nuke :) of course if nuke is falling already ghost can do this but... it will be too late to hit spacebar

Comment: @Meta: Spacebar does not have an effect on centering the nuke launch event. I address this more specifically in my comment on your answer.

Answer (score -2):

**edit**
*this answer is wrong*

Nuke launch creates event (it's displayed on left side and subtitles) and you will see a target of nuke by hitting spacebar (at least at 1.2.0 path, didn't tested after)
If there is some other event occurred after nuke - just press space bar once again to cycle through events. Or just click on icon at the left side.

This trick doesn't work with nydus (it's just a sound - no any event produced).

Comment: The nuke launch causes an event, but it is not one that can be jumped to by clicking it or hitting space. Try this yourself: Play a custom gave vs the AI and lob some nukes at them. Then, view the replay in first person perspective as the AI. Note you can center in on all of their events except the warning of nuke launches. You see the event, but clicking on it or hitting spacebar does not center you on the nuke's launch location like it does the other events.

Comment: Meta, moderators have no control on checkmarks and the asker didn't receive your flag. If your answer is unsalvageable, consider deleting it.

Comment: I cannot delete accepted answer